# Airflow BigQueryInsertJobOperator SQL file from different bucket configuration

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to figure out how to reference a sql file in a another path in the same bucket as the DAG. The path where the dag lives in the bucket is dags/. It works when I put the script in that path or a child of that path but I want it to be out of the dag path. Any ideas?

PATH_TO_UPLOAD_FILE_PREFIX = os.environ.get("GCP_GCS_PATH_TO_UPLOAD_FILE_PREFIX", "Test-Processing/")

```
PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "project-id")
BUCKET_1 = os.environ.get("GCP_GCS_BUCKET_1", "bucket-name")

with DAG(dag_id='dag_id',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval="@daily", 
start_date=days_ago(1), catchup=False

) as dag:

    insert_job_operator = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='insert_job_operator',
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": "{% include '../Scripts/script.sql' %}",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        }

    )
insert_job_operator
```

Comment: This is running in Cloud Composer, right?

Comment: Right, with the newest versions of Airflow and Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may define the path to [Data folder](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket) in [`template_searchpath`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.4/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html) argument in the DAG definition as a viable option.

Note that this works only on specific folders in Cloud Storage or mapped directories.

See working code below:

```py
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path


PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "<your-project>")


with DAG(dag_id='dag_id',schedule_interval="@daily", 
start_date=datetime(2022,6,22), catchup=False, template_searchpath = '/home/airflow/gcs/data/'

) as dag:

    insert_job_operator = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='insert_job_operator',
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": "{% include '20220621_script.sql' %}",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        },
        dag=dag

    )
    
insert_job_operator
```

[image]

[image]

Logs:

```
[2022-06-22, 01:52:50 UTC] {bigquery.py:2247} INFO - Executing: {'query': {'query': 'SELECT name, CAST (id AS string) as id, address FROM `your-project.your-dataset.your-table`;', 'useLegacySql': False}}
[2022-06-22, 01:52:50 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:324} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2022-06-22, 01:52:50 UTC] {bigquery.py:1560} INFO - Inserting job airflow_dag_id_insert_job_operator_2022_06_22T01_52_43_313003_00_00_d90ca3cd2e59501bd34d36064cc75c88
[2022-06-22, 01:52:51 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1279} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=dag_id, task_id=insert_job_operator, execution_date=20220622T015243, start_date=20220622T015249, end_date=20220622T015251
[2022-06-22, 01:52:51 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-06-22, 01:52:51 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Project History in Bigquery:
[image]

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I'll try that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Glad that my answer is useful to you. You may refer to this SO post: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Wait%20until%20you%20receive%20an,additional%20information%20%E2%80%93%20not%20for%20socializing.)